# How to read in data doc.data()

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ id }}
    {{ title }}
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
import 'firebase/firebase-firestore'
import { db } from '@/fdb'

export default {
  props: ['id'],
  data () {
    return {
      forms: [],
      form: {
        title: '',
        content: ''
      }
    }
  },
  async created () {
    const route = useRoute()
    const forminfo = db.collection('forms').doc(route.params.id)
    const doc = await forminfo.get()
    console.log(doc.data().title)
  }
}
</script>
```

I can print out the title through console.log(doc.data())

I tried to read doc.data() throgh {{ title }} in template
but i can't read it.

How can I read the doc.data() value from  template?

---

edited

I edited the question by referring to the firestore official document.

I checked the vue official document, but it was different from how I read the data stored in firestore.

Comment: Can you share the code of your template as well as the `data` part of your `script` part (i.e. what's in `export default {data() {return {}`)

Comment: I edited it by referring to the official website.
I don't know how to print out in the template.
I checked the vue official document, but It didn't work on how to read the data stored in firestore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do the trick. However, I would kindly suggest you read the introduction to Vue.js [template syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html) and [components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html) in order to understand the data object and the text interpolation using the “Mustache” syntax.

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ form.id }}
    {{ form.title }}
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
import 'firebase/firebase-firestore'
import { db } from '@/fdb'

export default {
  props: ['id'],
  data () {
    return {
      forms: [],
      form: {
        title: '',
        content: '',
        id: ''
      }
    }
  },
  async created () {
    const route = useRoute()
    const forminfo = db.collection('forms').doc(route.params.id)
    const doc = await forminfo.get()
    console.log(doc.data().title)
    this.form.title = doc.data().title;
    this.form.id = doc.id;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: thank you so much  i forgot add this.
I wasted two days on this matter.
ty tyty